How to fix steam-damage on cabinet
I set up a bottle sterilizer and tried to test it out, but it just exploded steam upwards. I quickly moved it out of the way but the damage was done. My cabinet now has two swollen/bubble spots. Not necessarily the most noticeable, but I am a renter so I don’t want to damage the property, especially if there is an easy way to fix it.
I think it may be a problem with the paint if anything, since when looking under the cabinet it looks like the paint has peeled away. I attached photos of the issue, including the bubbling effect I’m seeing on the cabinets, the bubbling compared to a regular cabinet, and the bottom of the damaged cabinet which is very noticeable.
Is there anyway to fix this?




It's not going to be easy, maybe impossible. Those are Thermofoil doors, a vinyl material molded to the shape of the door and then glued on to particle board. The steam over heated and shrunk the vinyl destroying the molded bottom edge. You might be able to re heat that edge and press, clamp those edges back into place. You could also check with cabinet companies to see if they can fix or replace the door.

One might get lucky and find good replacements at an online cabinet door supplier.  I've been pleasantly surprised by the cost/speed/quality of doors I've ordered.

Yes, one might be able to use a syringe or something to insert some glue into the bubble and press it into place (maybe with something hot) as it cures.  The part where it looks like the thermofoil has receded and shrunk, not so much.  Your best bet may be to simply paint.  Need to see more detail about that to make a better plan.
